# React-Quill : how to dynamically replace a text while typing, without loosing focus and keep the cursor at the correct place

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

This question is specificcally dedicated to react-quill. 
What I want to do : replace some text in a react-quill componement by an other while typing. For example: `#s1` will be replace by something like `productname(1eq, 100mg, 10ml)`. Be aware, I don't want to use JQuery.

So far I did it like this (code below), but once the modification is made, I lose the focus and don't know how to get it back. More over the console does throw an error of type "The given range isn't in document." 
So basically, it works, but the user has to click in the component to continue typing and if I have more than one react-quill component in the page it will scroll to the firt react-quill object (which is not conveniant when working on the last one).

```
class Procedure extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        content='';
    }
}

replaceTagByText(value){
   return value.replace(/#(\w+)\s/, myNewValue );
}

handleProcedureContentChange = (value) => {
    let newValue = replaceTagByText(value);
    this.setState({content:newValue});

};

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={styles.title}>My title</div>
        <ReactQuill
            key={"procedure_RTE_" + this.props.experimentId}
            value={this.state.content}
            modules={modules}
            formats={formats}
            onChange={this.handleProcedureContentChange}
        />

      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Please note that the code is over simplified, I use redux to serve my data, but the general idea is here.

The question is : how to properly replace a text in a react-quill while typing, without loosing focus and keep the cursor at the correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If finally find a solution. The idea is to keep track of the editor and just set the right setSelection. The updated code is bellow.

```
class Procedure extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        content='';
    }
}

replaceTagByText(value){
   return value.replace(/#(\w+)\s/, myNewValue );
}
//Modification of the code is there
handleProcedureContentChange = (value) => {
    let newValueObject = replaceTagByText(value);
    this.setState({content:newValueObject.value});
    quillRef = this.refs.myQuillRef.getEditor();
    //I need that settimeout to do it after the update of my redux logic
    setTimeout(() => {
      quillRef.focus();
      quillRef.setSelection(newValueObject.indexAfterInsertion, 0, myQuillRef);
    }, 500);

};

render() {
    let myRef = (el) => this.myQuillRef = el;
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={styles.title}>My title</div>
        <ReactQuill
            key={"procedure_RTE_" + this.props.experimentId}
            ref={myRef}
            value={this.state.content}
            modules={modules}
            formats={formats}
            onChange={()this.handleProcedureContentChange}
        />

      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works for plain text, but what if you wanted to wrap the text in an html tag? For instance, whatever your RegEx returns, let's say you want to wrap that in an `<a>` tag to make it a link. Any ideas?

Comment: @silencedogood, then write the right code that is interpreted by quill as a link. I don't remberber exactyl how to write it, but the data in Quill is plain text, so just write the correct tag in it. Look here: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/3009 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59544367/adding-link-to-quill-editor-causes-text-after-link-to-overflow. Good luck.